# c# UnitTest Mocking Setup of a class with GUID properties during each instance

Tags: c#

I'm trying to unit test some class mapping within a service that uses `UserManager<AppUser>`

I've hit a bump when trying to mock the `CreateUserAsync` method of my `UserManager`

```
mockUserManager.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(_newUser, PASSWORD))
   .ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);
```

Where my new user is established with very minimal info:

```
_newUser = new AppUser { UserName = "jim@test.com", Email = "jim@test.com" };
```

The problem is, because the AppUser (derived from IdentityUser) has a bunch of other properties populated during construction (e.g. concurrenct / security stamp, Id) as GUIDS there's no way my Mock will ever match the implementation when the user is created in the service!

**Is there any way I can use the mockUserManager.Setup() method to tell it to compare only specific properties??**

I thought I may be able to use the `It.Any()` method but then figured that's just for a range of stuff...

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what you want to test? What does your unit test currently look like? More code would be helpful. Do you use any `Verify(...)` calls on mock objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a specific value, you can tell Moq to accept any value by using something like `It.IsAny<string>` or `It.IsAny<AppUser>`. So your mock would become:

```
mockUserManager
    .Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<AppUser>, It.IsAny<string>))
    .ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);
```

This method will accept any user object and any password too.

Comment: Perfect for what I need and also shows me how this `It.IsAny` function works. I wonder about cases where someone may want only specific `AppUser`s to return a success but for now, I don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Actually as a cheat, since password is only a string, you could always force a setup to return Sucess or not based on the specific password rather than specific AppUser properties... that'd work but it's a bit hacky.